# Upper bound of multiple $\max$ operators

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, upper-lower-bounds

The value $l>0$ is bounded above by **either** of the following inequalities with $a,c>0$,

$$l \leq \max \{a, b\}$$ **or** $$l \leq \max\{c, d\}.$$

My though was $$l \leq \max \{\sqrt{ac},\sqrt{ad},\sqrt{bc},\sqrt{bd} \}, \quad l \geq0.$$
Is it correct? Can we found a **tight** upper bound of $l$?

**Note:** I am interested mostly for the case where $b=d=1$. However, a more general intuition on how we handle such problem is highly appreciated.

Comment: That will not work if for example $a>b>0$ and $c<d<-1$.  Even if they are all positive, it will not be tight

Comment: @Henry thanks for the response. I did some edits to fit in my problem. Is there a tight bound or a better bound?  In a more pedagogical point of view how do we handle something like this?

Comment: It seems to be correct to me. Assume $a>1$ and $c>1$ (the other cases are analogous). Then $ l\leq \min\{a,c\}$. Wlog assume $a\leq c$ then $a^2 \leq ac \leq c^2$ whence $l \leq \sqrt{ac}$ (since $a,c>0$), and we are done. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Desperado thanks for the response. I was thinking what would be the intersection of these two inequalities that is why I took all the combinations in the $\max$ operator. But I am not sure about this rationale.